# 404 и Slow network is detected после переноса сайта wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hosting

Есть сайт footbik.ua. Появилась необходимость его копирования на новые домены. При копировании на footbik.us все прошло без проблем. Базу копировал с помощью плагина duplicator а файлы по FTP. Сейчас возникла необходимость копирования сайта на домен footbik.kz, но теперь некоторые файлы не видит, хотя они есть на хостинге.Пробовал делать разрешения 755 на эти файлы и директории, но не помогло, так же крутил все возможные варианты редиректов http на https. Нужна помощь в общем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну 404 ж - физически нет файлов.

Comment: но они лежат там

Comment: Проверяй правильность путей, регистр имеет значение.

Answer (score 1):

Может это и не очевидно, но скорей всего дело в том что после переноса не изменили, или не везде изменили, название домена на новый.

Comment: Перенос был дуликатором всё там изменено.

Comment: Из файлов перенесено тоже почти все, кроме некоторых папок в wp-content/uploads. Их тоже не находит, но потому что их действительно нет, а вот файлы в wp-includes все на месте

Comment: как говорится "доверяй, но проверяй"

Answer (score 1):

Ответ оказался прост. Сделать все файлы 644 а папки 755

Comment: Никогда не трогай права. Какие сервер дал - те и должны быть Конечно если сервере настроен корректно (его вообще сложно настроить не правильно в отношении прав, но некоторые умудряются). Если же нет - права это лишь малая  часть проблем на таком хостинге

Comment: И да - в вопросе ты говорил, что права были (755 это выше 644). Так что были ещё косяки. Не в правах было дело.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не трогал права изначально) Они были неправильные. Просто нужен был домен kz, вроде выбрал лучший хостинг Казахстана. У них все хостинги "супер". Спасибо за попытку помочь.

Comment: Права нужно было всей иерархии делать, а не корневым или конечным папкам. Это моя ошибка была.

Comment: Но проблема Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSugdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2 не ушла.

Comment: 1. В КЗ нет нормальных хостингов в принципе. 2. Если бы права при распаковке архива были не достаточные, то было бы 403, а не 404. Тут дело в другом. Но и кривой хостинг скорее всего тоже.

Comment: только не `644 и 755`. мы же не компьютеры, мнемоника удобнее: `u=rw,go=r и u=rwx,go=rx`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Это кому как удобнее понимать.  :)